# What's the best way to compress or encode a list of numbers into a single alphanumeric string?

Tags: algorithm, string, encoding

What's the best way to compress or encode a list of numbers of arbitrary length and sizes into a single alphanumeric string?

The goal is to be able to convert something like 1,5,8,3,20,212,42 into something like a8D1jN to be used in a URL, and then back to 1,5,8,3,20,212,42.

For the resulting string I'm fine with any number and any ASCII letter, lowercase and uppercase, so: 0-9a-zA-Z. I prefer not to have any punctuation whatsoever.

Comment: What's the range of allowable characters? a-z, 0-9? Assume punctuation and case difference are out?

Comment: @Michael: I've updated the question to specify that.

Comment: *Best* in what regard? "d1d5d8…" was about as simple to interpret as "…x14xD4x2A" - oh well, see [Jens Schauder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3858442).

Answer (score 5):

If you consider your list as a string, then you have 11 different characters to encode (0-9 and comma). This can be expressed in 4 bits. If you were willing to add, say $ and ! to your list of acceptable characters, then you would have 64 different output characters, and thus be able to encode 6 bits per character.

This would mean that you could map the string to an encoded string that would be about 30% shorter than the original one, and fairly obfuscated and random looking.

This way you could transcode the number series [1,5,8,3,20,212,42] to the string "gLQfoIcIeQqq".

**UPDATE:** I felt inspired and wrote a python solution for this solution (not fast but functional enough...)

```py
    ZERO = ord('0')
    OUTPUT_CHARACTERS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789$!"

    def encode(numberlist):

        # convert to string -> '1,5,8,3,20,212,42'
        s = str(numberlist).replace(' ','')[1:-1]

        # convert to four bit values -> ['0010', '1011', '0110', ... ]
        # (add 1 to avoid the '0000' series used for padding later)
        four_bit_ints = [0 <= (ord(ch) - ZERO) <= 9 and (ord(ch) - ZERO) + 1 or 11 for ch in s]
        four_bits = [bin(x).lstrip('-0b').zfill(4) for x in four_bit_ints]

        # make binary string and pad with 0 to align to 6 -> '00101011011010111001101101...'
        bin_str = "".join(four_bits)
        bin_str = bin_str + '0' * (6 - len(bin_str) % 6)

        # split to 6bit blocks and map those to ints
        six_bits = [bin_str[x * 6 : x * 6 + 6] for x in range(0, len(bin_str) / 6)]
        six_bit_ints = [int(x, 2) for x in six_bits]

        # map the 6bit integers to characters
        output = "".join([OUTPUT_CHARACTERS[x] for x in six_bit_ints])

        return output

    def decode(input_str):

        # map the input string from characters to 6bit integers, and convert those to bitstrings
        six_bit_ints = [OUTPUT_CHARACTERS.index(x) for x in input_str]
        six_bits = [bin(x).lstrip('-0b').zfill(6) for x in six_bit_ints]

        # join to a single binarystring
        bin_str = "".join(six_bits)

        # split to four bits groups, and convert those to integers
        four_bits = [bin_str[x * 4 : x * 4 + 4] for x in range(0, len(bin_str) / 4)]
        four_bit_ints = [int(x, 2) for x in four_bits]

        # filter out 0 values (padding)
        four_bit_ints = [x for x in four_bit_ints if x > 0]

        # convert back to the original characters -> '1',',','5',',','8',',','3',',','2','0',',','2','1','2',',','4','2'
        chars = [x < 11 and str(x - 1) or ',' for x in four_bit_ints]

        # join, split on ',' convert to int
        output = [int(x) for x in "".join(chars).split(',') if x]

        return output


    if __name__ == "__main__":

        # test
        for i in range(100):
            numbers = range(i)
            out = decode(encode(numbers))
            assert out == numbers

        # test with original series
        numbers = [1,5,8,3,20,212,42]
        encoded = encode(numbers)
        print encoded         # prints 'k2UBsZgZi7uW'
        print decode(encoded) # prints [1, 5, 8, 3, 20, 212, 42]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use an encoding scheme like the [`Base64`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Base64 modules or libraries are common in multiple programming languages.

Comment: Base64 will convert to both uppercase and lowercase - that may not be what the OP wants. Base36 is closer, but lacks inbuilt implementations in most frameworks.

Comment: I'm fine with uppercase and lowercase. What I'm not sure about is whether I should just use a coma as separator; seems like a waste if you think in binary, but I might be wrong.

Comment: The comma would be needed if the numbers are not all the same size. If they are then you would be using extra space to represent the smaller numbers. For instance '1' takes one byte of space as a character, but 4 bytes as a number.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of comma separating the numbers, you could do a simple encoding where you replace the last digit of each number with 'a'+digit. So, your list `[1,5,8,3,20,212,42]` would become mysterious looking `bfid2a21c4c`. :)

I would use something like this only if there are a handful of numbers, where compression won't be able to shorten the string a lot. If it s a lot of numbers we are talking about, you could try to perform some sort of compression + base64 encoding on the data instead.

Comment: I like this idea, simple and elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the range of the numbers -- with a reasonable range a simple [dictionary compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_coder) scheme could work.

Given your edit and estimate of 10k rows, a dictionary scheme where each number is mapped to a triple of [A-Za-z0-9] could be unique for 62*62*62 different entries.

Comment: The numbers are ids in the database; I'm not sure if it would ever constitute a reasonable range (I don't expect it to grow a lot, definitely not above 10k), I'll look into dictionary compression. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a super cool and efficient algorithm for your case. However, a very simple, tested, and reliable algorithm would be to use a "common" encoding or compression algorithm on the comma seperated string of numbers.

There are many available to choose from.

Comment: What do you mean by a common encoding or compression algorithm?

Comment: The ones that come to mind right now are BZip, GZip, and Deflate.

Comment: For small sequences, these algorithms can often increase the size of the data significantly due to headers and hash tables. for english text strings, there is a nice example called smaz. For numbers, it is a litle more complex because the number 127 takes up 1 byte but the unicode string "127" takes up 6 bytes. You can't make nothing out of something universally, but if your data has a predictable format then the rules of it's construction can be used to create a subset that can be compressed.

Answer (score 0):

'best' depends on what your criteria are.

If best means *simple* : just string the numbers together seperated by a fixed character:

1a5a8a3a20a212a42

This should also be *fast*

If you want the resulting string to be *small*, you can run the string above through some compression algorithm like zip, then the result through some encoding like base64 or similar.

Comment: I reckon zip and base64 will both make this string longer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Chinese Remainder Theorem as well.

The idea is to find a number X such that

```
X = a1 mod n1
X = a2 mod n2
...
X = ak mod nk
```

gcd(Ni Nj)=1 for each combination (i j).

The CRT says how to find a smallest number X that satisfies these equations.

Like this, you can encode the numbers a1...ak as X, and keep a  list of Ns fixed. Each Ni must be greater than ai, quite so.